# Verticall align of div

Tags: html, css

I need to align the red triangle in the middle of the div with the text, but I made several unsuccessful attempts.

http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/207191/

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2 opt ">teste
    testetestete
    uaoijpajpa
    ]jpiajpiajpo
    piajpajpoçajp

    dada
    dadad
    hjaojpaj
    kpakák
    pjapp--´q
    oiaijaçlma
    kjpoakpa-k
    </div>
      <div class="col wrp p-0">
        <div class="tri"></div>
      </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.opt {
      border: 1px solid red;
      color: red;
      display: block;
    }
    .wrp {
      padding-top: 50%;
    }
    .tri {
      width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 15px solid transparent;
        border-left: 12px solid red;
        border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    }
```

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'with the text', but heres a simple way to center vertically. position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);

Comment: 'with the text' means with the div 'opt'

Comment: @ChrisLi your solution worked, thnks a lot!

Comment: I recommend with flexbox, learn this web https://flexboxfroggy.com/

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way, just add **margin: auto 0;** to your **.wrp** class (It will take automatic margin from top and bottom according to your content) and remove **padding-top: 50%**. As you have added a border on .col class so it will show the border if you want you can remove the border. here is the code:

```
    .wrp {
      margin: auto 0;
      border: 0;
    }
```

Try it now: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/207289/

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following property to class tri:

```
top: 50%;
position: relative;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

`position: relative` allow other property that could shift the element from his normal position

`top: 50%` would set the vertical position of the triangle to 50% from its container.

`transform: translateY(-50%)` shift the triangle up by half of his own height

Answer (score 0):

Try it now,

http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/207230/

I have added

```
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
```

to the `.tri` class